# How should I update object value from UserDefaults?

Tags: swift

There's Struct like below

```
struct User:Codable {
    static var shared = User()
    var name:String!
    var age:Int!
}
```

User can save their info

```
var userInfo = User.shared
userInfo.name = "Kevin"
userInfo.age = 28
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(userInfo), forKey:"UserInformation")
```

I have tried below

but it seems to create new object

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(userInfo.age == 32), forKey:"UserInformation")
```

Is it possible just update userInfo object from UserDefault?

like only change userInfo.age = 32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode the object, change its value, then encode it back again:

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "UserInformation") else {
    // no data associated with the key!
}
guard var obj = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) else {
    // something wrong happened with decoding 
}
obj.age = 32 // changing the object...
guard let newData = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(obj) else {
    // something wrong happened with encoding
}
UserDefaults.standard.set(newData, forKey: "UserInformation")
```